# How to write queries to file rather than executing them

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
engine = sqlalchemy.engine.create_engine('mysql://py:123@localhost/py', echo=True)
con = engine.connect()
res = con.execute("insert into user set name = %s", 'A')
```

How do I write this query to a (.sql) file (or how do I assign it to a variable)?
I'd rather not do all the escaping myself.

Comment: Personally, I’d put it in a stored procedure.

Comment: re: "I'd rather not do all the escaping myself." – Does that mean you want the literal query with the values embedded, e.g., `INSERT INTO "user" (name) VALUES ('A')` …?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have the fully formatted query.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `literal_binds` to produce an SQL statement with the values embedded:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# …

user = sa.Table("user", sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)
user_insert = sa.insert(user).values(name="A")
compiled_text = str(
    user_insert.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
)
print(compiled_text)
# INSERT INTO "user" (name) VALUES ('A')
```

However, be careful about using that with untrusted inputs as there is still the possibility of SQL injection issues.

Comment: If this is insecure, doesn't that mean proper escaping is NOT being done?

Comment: SQLAlchemy does basic escaping, e.g. `O'Leary` → `'O''Leary'`, but the best choice for integrating data into an SQL statement is to pass the values as parameters and let the DBAPI layer *for that specific database* protect against the more esoteric injection cases (e.g., using encoded characters instead of literals). SQLAlchemy's `.compile()` method can also be used to generate the parameterized query and the parameter values separately.